# Why would I want to bind OracleCommand parameters by position?

Tags: c#, oracle

So I've stumbled upon a what I'll call a quirk in `OracleCommand`. By default `BindByName` is set to `false`. In this case, they will be applied to your query in the order they are added to the `OracleCommand`, not by the name of the parameter.

This caused me all kinds of grief until I figured out that the parameters were not being applied to my query as I expected.

Why would I want to do this? Is there a significant performance impact I'm missing here or is it just for compatibility with a previous version of `OracleCommand`?

Comment: By default Oracle binds variable by position, not by name. This is probably why...

Comment: That's pretty much why it probably exists, 30y ago they hadn't thought of naming parameters. But that doesn't explain to me why I'd want to do it as a developer today?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do bind by position if you wanted to bind different values/parameters to two or more binds that were given the same name.

Although I can't explain why you as the developer would name the binds the same if you didn't want to bind the same parameters to them.

Most likely this is due to legacy functionality where named binds didn't exist in previous versions of OracleCommand, and when named binds were introduced the default was to use positional binding to prevent breakage of legacy code.